# In a a function, round values based on different conditions

Tags: r

I want to round these values but they are diverse so I cant set a general rule, like round(pvalue,2). How do I accomplish this?

```
id <- LETTERS[1:10]
pvalue <- c(0.3,0.0432,0.0032,0.67,0.00000003,0.0069,0.782, 0.0004, 0.00076,0.341)
df <- data.frame(id,pvalue)
df


    id  pvalue
1   A 0.30000000
2   B 0.04320000
3   C 0.00320000
4   D 0.67000000
5   E 0.00000003
6   F 0.00690000
7   G 0.78200000
8   H 0.00040000
9   I 0.00076000
10  J 0.34100000
```

It should look like:

```
   id  pvalue
1   A     0.3
2   B    0.04
3   C   0.003
4   D    0.67
5   E <0.0001
6   F   0.007
7   G    0.78
8   H  0.0004
9   I  0.0007
10  J    0.34
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong tool. If you want to prepare p values for scientific display you can use the function [pvalString](https://rdrr.io/cran/lazyWeave/man/pvalString.html) in [lazyWeave](https://rdrr.io/cran/lazyWeave/) to convert your numeric values into correctly formatted strings.

```
library(lazyWeave)

pvalue <- c(0.3,0.0432,0.0032,0.67,0.00000003,0.0069,0.782, 0.0004, 0.00076,0.341)
pvalString(pvalue)
```

You can edit the parameters to get exactly what you want but the default settings will give you the standard convention.

```
 [1] "0.30"    "0.043"   "0.003"   "0.67"    "< 0.001" "0.007"   "0.78"    "< 0.001" "< 0.001" "0.34"
```